# unable to get the following UI in my android app

Tags: android, user-interface

In my app i have a list view, in that i need to place the following UI[image]

As shown in the above image i am able to get the rounded background in a linear layout of orientation vertical. So that i have placed the following in order
1. TextView
2. ImageView in FrameLayout so that a TextView can be placed over the ImageView inside FrameLayout
3. and again a TextView

```
Now my problem is 
1. i want to place the image view of the calendar icon at the top right corner, so that a part of the icon gets placed over the image view 
2. The image inside the Frame layouts imageview is received from an url without round corners. I want to show round corners over the image
```

Following is my layout contents

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@drawable/img_bg"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_list_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_margin="6dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:id="@+id/event_list_image"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="280dp"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:background="@drawable/offer_title_bg"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_overlay_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_timing_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to make this UI possible....

Comment: put your code my friend i will edit and send it to you

Comment: Google Researcher - i have added my code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout and alignTop:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_list_image"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="110dip"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:src="@drawable/main0x" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_overlay_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/event_list_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should change properties like: `android:layout_below`, `android:layout_above`, `android:layout_alignTop`, `android:layout_marginTop` and ...

Comment: I updated my answer. but it is not possible for me to edit your layout remotely. put both text and image in a RelativeLayout and change settings I have mentioned